# C# - Call subclass with a subobject

Tags: c#

See the code below.

In the base handler (`MyBaseHandler`) I have a handler of all objects of `MyBaseClass`.
Then I have a subclass handler (`HandlerA`) where I want to handle the objects of class `ClassA`.
So I want to override the base handler for class ClassA; all other classes should have the base handling.

But this does not work as expected. The base `Handle(MyBaseClass)` is called for all the objects, including `objA` where I want to use `Handle(ClassA)`.

I would like this generic handing so I can easily extend with other handling for other classes as needed.  This code compiles. If I add the "override" keyword to the Handle in HandlerA it will not compile.

How can achieve what I want with the simplest code? Is it possible to achieve this without a lot of code to check the type of the class? Is it possible to use generics to achieve this?

```
abstract class MyBaseClass {}
class ClassA : MyBaseClass {}
class ClassB : MyBaseClass {}
class ClassC : MyBaseClass {}
class ClassD : MyBaseClass {}

abstract class MyBaseHandler
{
    public void Go()
    {
        ClassA objA = new ClassA();
        Handle(objA);
    
        ClassB objB = new ClassB();
        Handle(objB);
    
        ClassC objC = new ClassC();
        Handle(objC);
    
        ClassD objD = new ClassD();
        Handle(objD);   
    }

    public virtual void Handle(MyBaseClass obj)
    {
        ...
    }
}       

public class HandlerA : MyBaseHandler
{
    public void Handle(ClassA obj)
    {
        // This code does not get called.
        ...
    }
    
    public void Run()
    {
        Go();
    }
}
```

Comment: When you want to override a method like your `Handle()` method, you have to use the keyword `override`, otherwise you just add a new method which exist in parallel to the already existing method.

Comment: @Progman, with the `override` keyword the code will not compile because there is "no suitable method to override"

Comment: Maybe an `if (obj is ClassA) { ... } else { ... }` in `public override void Handle(MyBaseClass obj) { ... }` is enough here?

Comment: @Jimi, I would like to avoid a lot of checking the type in the code. Can it be done simpler?

Comment: @VilhelmH. Exactly. The method you want to override is `Handle(MyBaseClass)`, so the method parameter list must still be `Handle(MyBaseClass ...)`, not `Handle(ClassA ...)`.

Comment: Overriding with this signature is illegal. Your subclass method cannot handle all subtypes of MyBaseClass. You should read about covariance and contravariance.

Comment: `switch (obj) { case ClassA a when obj is ClassA: /*[...]*/ break; default: /*[...]*/ break;}` :) -- You could use interfaces and make it *more generic*. To determine based on a real use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MyBaseHandler` only knows about `Handle(MyBaseClass obj)`. It doesn't matter that `Handle` has the same name as a method in `MyBaseHandler`, or even that the signatures are compatible. If you were to override `Go` in `HandlerA`, your code would work as expected, but as it is, **`MyBaseHandler` can never resolve to a method defined in a sub-class**.

You are on the right track making the method `virtual` in `MyBaseHandler`, but you need to follow through and create an override in `HandlerA`:

```cs
class HandlerA : MyBaseHandler
{
    public override void Handle(MyBaseClass obj)
    {
        if (obj is ClassA)
        {
            Handle(obj);
            return;
        }
        base.Handle(obj);
    }
    
    public void Handle(ClassA obj)
    {
        // This code gets called by override void Handle(MyBaseClass obj)
    }

    // ...
}
```

Since `Handle(MyBaseClass obj)` matches the signature of the base class, you are able to override and `MyBaseHandler` can *"see"* the method. You can then check if `obj` is an instance of `ClassA` and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

This is not going to work, because compiler expects method with signature indicating MyBaseClass as argument. If you want to override it, the signature should be the same, so in `HandlerA` it should be `override void Handle(MyBaseClass obj)`. `ClassA` inherits from `MyBaseClass`, so it will still take it as argument. You can then cast it inside function if you need it to be `ClassA`.

```
public override void Handle(MyBaseClass obj)
{
    ClassA objA = obj as ClassA;
    if(objA == null) 
    {
         throw new ArgumentNullException("Argument to this handler should be ClassA") ;
    } 
    // your code
}
```

Comment: I advise against this. Violates the Liskov Substitution Principle (the L in the SOLLID principles). In other words, it is a frail abstraction.